# How to install Apache 2 on Windows 10?

Tags: windows, apache, installation

I want to install an Apache 2 server on a Windows 10 system. The official documentation (https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/platform/windows.html) states that:

> "The Apache HTTP Server Project itself does not provide binary releases of software, only source code"

To have a binary of the Apache HTTP Server it has to be compiled by oneself or acquired from a distribution provided by a thrid party. These distributions usually bundle Apache with PHP and MySQL.

The question is:

**What distribution is recommended to install a standalone Apache 2 server and what are the steps to do it?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have used the Apache Lounge distribution indicated in the official Apache 2 documentation (https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/platform/windows.html)

These are the steps to install Apache on Windows using Apache Lounge distribution:

1. Download **Apache 2.4.37 Win64** (https://www.apachelounge.com/download/)
2. Create folder **C:/Apache24**
3. Unzip **httpd-2.4.37-win64-VC15.zip** in folder **C:/Apache24**

#### Option 1: To run it from the console:

4. Open **Windows Power Shell**
5. Execute **httpd.exe**

   ```
   PS > C:\Apache24\bin\httpd.exe
   ```

   or

   ```
   PS > cd C:\Apache24\bin
   PS > .\install.exe
   ```
6. Open **http:\localhost** or **http:\127.0.0.1** in brwoser

> The message **It works!** will be displayed

#### Option 2: To install it as a service:

4. Open **Windows Power Shell**
5. Open **Windows Power Shell** as administrator

   ```
   PS > Start-Process PowerShell -Verb RunAs
   ```
6. Install the service

   ```
   PS > cd C:\Apache24\bin
   PS > .\httpd.exe -k install
   ```
7. Start the service

   ```
   PS > .\httpd.exe -k start
   ```

   or through the services administrator

   ```
   PS > services.msc
   Select Apache2.4 > Right-click > Start
   ```
8. Open **http:\localhost** or **http:\127.0.0.1** in brwoser

> The message **It works!** will be displayed

Comment: In Option 1, step 5  what is the difference between httpd.exe and install.exe; to me, httpd.exe seems temporary and install.exe seems permanent.

Answer (score 1):

### Easy:

1. Download from apache lounge https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/platform/windows.html
2. Go into downloaded zip folder and move the Apache24 folder to C:/
3. Open terminal to C:/Apache24/bin and execute httpd.exe

done!

Now type "localhost" into your browser and a message "It works" should appear on screen.